# Mount cloudbees repository via WebDAV under Mac OSX Mavericks and write files to it

Tags: macos, webdav, cloudbees

I have a public cloudbees repository and I would like to store some more files in that repository.

My client is a MacBook running OSX Mavericks 10.9.5 , I can mount the repo via Finder --> Connect to Server... then I enter my public HTTPS address and I see the folder in my Finder.

But I can not write to it. Why? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found it out!

**Solution**

If you login to your Cloudbees Admin Center (https://console.cloudbees.com) it displays your EMail address on the top right. So I thought that my EMail is also my username.

However, the username is also stored in the profile (click on settings to find that out).

So if you connect via Finder to your Cloudbees repository, you don't have to enter that EMail and password but rather your **Cloudbees username and password**. This is quite irritating as the Cloudbees Admin Page does not show your username on the top right...

I hope this will also help others with the same problem!